# memory issue on python image save

Tags: python, image, memory-management

I have "denoiser" function that take a list on images and convert them

and when i resave the list the memory jump *2

I'M thinking to try

1. add one file from list than delete from the old object
2. save the object list! **converted_image_list.save**

```
   with Image.open(im) as img:
      converted_image_list.append(img.convert("L"))
print("converted_image_list is now 4G")
im1 = converted_image_list[0]
print(" im1.save will double the memory")
im1.save(new_path, save_all=True, append_images=converted_image_list[1:])
```

Comment: Why are you even holding the contents of multiple images in memory? Make a list of just the NAMES, open one at a time, do your processing one at a time and move on. You shouldn't need or want to hold the contents of multiple independent images in memory at once.

Comment: at first it's a PDF and we parse and run some algorithms on it, so you suggest im1.save in the for loop that contains the "with Image..."?